# Send email links to all emails in DB based on catgory

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website where a user can post qn job request/add through an email form. This data is also stored in DB, under the table `jobadd`, which has a column named `Kategori`.   And in this `kategori` i have a row named "bygg" the job request/add is posted under. And i also have one column named "Länk" (my language for "Link") and this column there will be a link to the job request/add so when a user gets this link in the email they can click it to see the posting online.

I also have a second page where companies can register and choose a category that fits them.  In this case the category will be "Bygg & Anläggning" so this data is also stored in DB under `USERS`.  In this table I have a column named `Kategori` and the row "Bygg & Anläggnig, this row will describe what category the company has registered under. Also in this table I have the `email` column where the company's email address is stored.

The code works like:  When running this script, it will send out one link (the most recent) if no older that one day from `jobadd->Kategori->Bygg` and the link. To all the emails in the `USERS->Kategori->Bygg & Anläggning->email`.

So this works fine (Hope my description is not to hard to understand):
But what i would like this code to do is to send out all the links if not older that one day.

I have tried to move and change the code, and the closest I got is this:  4 links in the category Bygg and 4 emails in the email column, results in one email with one link, the second email with two links, the third email with three links, and the fourth email has four links.  I want all four emails to receive all the four links.
And if there are only links older that one day, I don't want the script to send any emails at all.

Like it is now even if the script won't find a link that is no older that one day, it will send out an empty email to all emails in the column email under the table USERS.

```
//CONNECT TO MYSQL
$link=mysql_connect($mysqladd, $mysqluser, $mysqlpass, true) or die('Could not connect to database: ' . mysql_error());

//CONNECT TO DATABASE
mysql_select_db($databasename, $link) or die('Could not connect to table: ' . mysql_error());

$query="SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(Time_of_Submission, '%Y/%m/%d') FROM jobadd  WHERE Kategori='bygg' AND Time_of_Submission BETWEEN SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND SYSDATE() ORDER BY ID DESC"; 
$query2="SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE Kategori='Bygg & Anläggning'";

$result=mysql_query($query); 
$result2=mysql_query($query2);
$mailmessage = mysql_fetch_array($result);  
$num=mysql_numrows($result); 
$num=mysql_numrows($result2);

if (!mysql_query($query,$link)) 
{ 
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

mysql_close($link);

$message .= $mailmessage['Länk']."\n";

$i=0; 
while ($i < $num) {
    $email=mysql_result($result2,$i,"email");
    $fromemail = "no_reply@jobler.se"; 
    $subject = "Det har kommit in en ny Tjänstförfrågan på Jobler.se som passar er profil (klicka på länken nedan)"; 
    mail($email, $subject, $message, "From: $fromemail"); 
    echo "Förfrågan skickad till följande E-post adresser:";
    echo "<b><br>$email</b><hr><br>";
    echo "<b><br>$message</b><hr><br>";
    $i++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have a default value in the link column, and use an if statement in the loop.

```
if $message=='default text in column'
{
echo "No link";
}
```